# Solr Search Sharding For a different Reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sharding

So I have looked all over SO for this but I am trying to shard a solr index not for its size but because my data is sensitive and some of our clients want it hosted in a certain country.

I have a Canada DB and server instance that has a solr index stored there but I cant store the Ireland index in Canada. It needs to be in Ireland too.

From all the information I have read so far, the sharded index in solr acts in a master slave situation but I cant have it like that since my client does not want their solr index anywhere but in Ireland. (Some people are so anal!)

Here is my final goal:

I want someone to log into my app and have my app let them search their database shard with their solr shard all from a database and a solr index in ireland. I want the same for Canada.

Any help to get me on the right path would be very appreciated. I am new to sharding.

EDIT: I guess sharding is so that all the solr instances can communicate to the same index overall. I need a way to redirect you to a different index.

EDIT #2: Is there anything I can do with the solr request handler and point it to different urls?

Comment: Do you ever need to merge results from the Ireland database and Canada database? If not, then just setup two independent Solr installs and direct the user's query to the correct install from your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I never need the data to come back together but there are other limitations so I can't just set up a new install. That may be where I have to go in the end but its my last resort.

Comment: Due to boss limitations.